# GWT: How do I layout widgets horizontally?

Tags: gwt, panel

I'm using GWT 2.4.  I'm having trouble laying out widgets horizontally in a pane of my TabLayoutPanel.  How do I lay out panels horizontally and then have the widgets wrap to the next line when there is no more visible room?  Loosely, I create the TabLayoutPanel like so ...

```
tabsPanel = new TabLayoutPanel(BAR_HEIGHT_IN_EM, Style.Unit.EM);
for (final Node tabNode : documentNode.getChildren()) {
    final ScrollPanel scrollPanel = new ScrollPanel();
    ...
    Widget childWidget = createPanelFromWidgets(childWidgets);
    ...
    scrollPanel.add(childWidget);
    tabsPanel.add(scrollPanel, tabName);
}


public static Widget createPanelFromWidgets(final List<Widget> childWidgets) { 
    final FlowPanel horizPanel = new FlowPanel();
    for (final Widget childWidget : childWidgets) { 
        horizPanel.add(childWidget);
    }   // for
    return horizPanel;
}   // createPanelFromWidgets
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?  I thought the documentation () says things would be automatically laid out horizontally, but I'm seeing everything laid out vertically.

- Dave

PS - HorizontalPanel isn't an option because I want my elements to wrap when there is no more visible area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you put objects in a FlowPanel you get the default HTML layout behavior, not necessarily a horizontal layout.  If you check the styling of your widgets using firebug or something similar, they probably use "display: block;" (most do).  With a block display, they appear vertically.

If you change the CSS display attribute of each childWidget to "inline-block" or "inline", they should align horizontally and also wrap.